# Invalid .afpkg file - how to find more info?

Tags: c#, azure, emulation, appfabric

I have a simple Azure AppFabric (June CTP) project which just has one WCF service. It compiles and all seems OK - until I try to run it in the emulator, when I get this error message:

```
[Error]: Emulator exception caught: C:\Correct\Path\Correct.file.name.afpkg does not refer to a valid file.
```

I know this isn't enough to find out what's wrong, but I don't know how to find more info on this problem. How can I find more debug info? Google can't find anything about this error message...

The path is correct and it points to the correct file, which seems to be a valid .zip file...

Comment: I found the cause of my problem (I had an application definition name with dots in it, which I changed - but not the assembly name. Fixing this fixed the problem), but I would still like to know the answer to my question: How can I find more debug info in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the November CTP improves error messages.

In the meantime, attaching a debugger and a decompiler (e.g. [Reflector](http://www.reflector.net/)) to the emulator may help you to figure out where the problem is.

The latest paid-for version of Reflector allows you to set breakpoints or break on exceptions in decompiled code: I've earned back the money I paid for it several times over in the last couple of months.

Comment: There's a November CTP of AppFabric? I didn't know, and Google isn't helping me much... Where can I find this CTP?

Comment: http://www.microsoft.com/windowsazure/sdk/ and http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2011/11/14/updated-windows-azure-sdk-amp-windows-azure-hpc-scheduler-sdk.aspx refer.

Comment: Very nice - going into explore mode :-)